# New host, popups now blocked

Tags: web-hosting, google-chrome

We have a legitimate popup on our site which is when the user hits the live chat button a window appears with the chat inside. This worked no problem. We recently switched to a new host, and now the popup is blocked. Are popup blockers somehow aware of the host IP (which will have changed)? If so, I can only assume this previous IP was "bad" and hence it got blocked, is there a way to amend this (this was using Chrome).

**Original JS Code**

```
<a href="contact-us" class="button green icon" onclick='lpButtonCTTUrl = &#39;http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/12345678/?cmd=file&amp;file=visitorWantsToChat&amp;site=12345678&amp;referrer=&#39;+escape(document.location); lpButtonCTTUrl = (typeof(lpAppendVisitorCookies) != &#39;undefined&#39; ? lpAppendVisitorCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl) : lpButtonCTTUrl); lpButtonCTTUrl = ((typeof(lpMTag)!=&#39;undefined&#39; &amp;&amp; typeof(lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies)!=&#39;undefined&#39;)?lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl):lpButtonCTTUrl);window.open(lpButtonCTTUrl,&#39;chat12345678&#39;,&#39;width=475,height=400,resizable=yes&#39;);return false;'>ChatNow</a>
```

Readable version of the onclick part:

```
lpButtonCTTUrl = "http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/12345678/?cmd=file&amp;file=visitorWantsToChat&amp;site=12345678&amp;referrer=" + escape(document.location);
lpButtonCTTUrl = (typeof(lpAppendVisitorCookies) != "undefined" ? lpAppendVisitorCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl) : lpButtonCTTUrl);
lpButtonCTTUrl = ((typeof(lpMTag)!="undefined" && typeof(lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies)!="undefined")?lpMTag.addFirstPartyCookies(lpButtonCTTUrl):lpButtonCTTUrl);
window.open(lpButtonCTTUrl,"chat12345678","width=475,height=400,resizable=yes");
return false;
```

Comment: "Normally" popup blockers will not block popups which were created by a user click, but only those which appear "not by an intended user action" (like a click). Is it possible, that there is another problem, like a redirect or a javascript error on you page that actually prevents the popup from appearing?

Comment: It did turn out that there were some problems with the JS code I was using, so that got updated and fixed my problem. What still confuses me, switching between hosts is the *only* thing that happened, there definitely wasn't any code changes. So the question now is, why did it work before?

Comment: Javascript execution is domain-safe by default. So maybe the javascript is loaded from a place that has the "old" host setting (ip/domain name). When the domain changed during your host change (using another subdomain is enough: www vs. non-www), then there may be a security issue which will be logged in the js console of your browser.

Comment: Apologies I don't fully understand all the technicalities in that paragraph. The JS is loaded from the third party, not held on my site. Is this what you are referring to with "loaded from a place that has the 'old' host setting"? I've put back the broken code for trials sake, nothing is appearing in the console when I click the button and get the popup block diagram (testing in Chrome)

Comment: So you changed the code as well? Then this may be the problem. Do you just move to a different hosting or did you edit the code additionally? (Then please provide some of it)

Comment: I've changed the code in order to get it working, but that was only after it was deployed on the new server and the problem started. Originally when I set up the website on the new server ready for switching over, I left the code completely untouched, expecting it just to work as it did before. I've added the original code to my question (too long for the comment).

Comment: Ok, I see. So the cross-domain problem is not an issue here as you include the whole js into the onclick attribute of the link (which is considered bad practice). I think the solution of your second question then lies in the specific error you got on the console.

Comment: No error in the console unfortunately. I guess this may go unsolved, although hopefully it's not a problem for most if the JS they are using is valid/correct in the first place, it's just because mine was a bit dodgy.